# IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue+function

Tags: c++

A very easy problem but i cant fix it.
Here I have

```
struct Person{
    char name[20];
    char family[20];
    char tel[20]; 
};

Person p[40];
string newName
```

and

```
p[ numPerson ].name = newName;
```

I want to write a function in which I can replace p[numPerson].name with newName but there's an error !: IntelliSense: expression must be a modifiable lvalue 
Hope someone can help !

Comment: `char name[20]` isn't a `std::string`. Why don't you use `string name;` to declare it in your `struct Person`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char name[20];
string newName
```

These both are different species. And as you know different species don't mix up with each other so easily.

Better way is to use std::string all through.

Answer (score 0):

You can  solve this problem by below methods 
1.

```
 struct Person{
        char name[20];
        char family[20];
        char tel[20];
    }Person p[40];
char  newName[20];
strcpy(p[numPerson].name,newName);
```

2.
Note: If you would like to change family , tel e.t.c value then make their data type string too.

```
struct Person{
            string name;
            char family[20];
            char tel[20];
        }Person p[40];
    string newName;
    p[numPerson].name = newName;
```

Comment: It's quite unusual for such fixed-length `char` fields to always be zero-terminated. If they aren't zero-terminated, `strcpy` will attempt to read beyond the end of `newName` and attempt to write beyond the end of `name`.

Comment: In that case `memcopy , strncpy` can be used .